# How to access variables in Perl from the config file for SSL cipher list

Tags: linux, perl, ssl, encryption, ssl-certificate

I am new to perl , need to edit the code in a way that the code takes the cipher-list from another file say B file.The cipherlist should be a variable in another file B(config file), the value of the variable has to be used in 'IO:Socket' object used in the Perl code in file A.

Below is the code from the file A(bin file). Instead of 'SSL cipher list' line (3rd line), it  has to be edited  in such a way that it takes the value of the cipher list (as variable) from the B file (config file).

**A file:**

```
# Create the SSL Socket:
if($useSSL) {
$socket = 10::Socket::SSL->new(
PeerAddr    => "${address}",
PeerPort    => "${port}",
SSL cipher list =>'ECDH+AES128:ECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES:DH+AESGCM:DH+AES256:RSA+AES:RSA+AESGCM:LaNULL:!RC4:!MD5:!DSS:!3DES:!SSLy3'A
)
```

Below lines I have selectively pasted instead of including all the lines.Config file is already defined in the code:

**A file (bin file)** :

```
$args{ ' client '} && do { client (

'address' => $args{address},

' config' => $config,
```

**B file (config file)** . Need to edit here as well , this looks something like :

```
   .................................... # 

Daemon Section # ################## section daemon
set listenTimeout        
set port        
set ssl        
set http        
set sslKey
set sslCert        
set maxConnections
set shimDir
```